# How to create bootable USB drive for Deepin OS 20

Tags: deepin

I downloaded the latest Deepin OS 20 from their website. Verified the checksum and it's perfect.

Now when I try to create a bootable usb stick using the iso it just doesn't work. Using `Startup Disk Creator` try to select Deepin Iso but it won't pick up. If I try the same with Ubuntu image it works well.

Here is a video.

[image]

Comment: The Ubuntu Startup Disk Creator is made for Ubuntu and the Ubuntu family flavours (Kubuntu, Lubuntu ... Xubuntu). You can use another cloning tool, that can clone from a file to a drive, for example **Disks** alias `gnome-disks` or [**mkusb**](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb). -- But if a cloning tool does not work with Deepin, you had better download and use [**Deepin's own tool to create a USB boot drive**](https://github.com/linuxdeepin/deepin-boot-maker).

Comment: @sudodus Ok now that I know this.. I tried to build the deepin tool as on linux we need to build it from the source. So that didn't go very well. I tried using *Disks* but not very sure what cloning means over here. I thought this would have been simpler.

Comment: In the meantime I downloaded Deepin and tested **cloning with [mkusb](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb)**. It works :-) So I suggest that you try that. (If I understand correctly, you are running Ubuntu or an Ubuntu flavour, because you mentioned the Startup Disk Creator.) -- By the way, cloning is described as 'Restore' in Disks.

Answer (score 0):

you can use dd `dd bs=4M if=path/to/deepin.iso of=/dev/sdx status=progress oflag=sync`. /dev/sdx is your USB, here use e.g sdb not sdb1. Be sure that is not mount, to check use `lsblk` and then if its mount do `umount /dev/sdx1`. Be careful.